# How to receive the TIME_TICK intent

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

This isn't a very advanced question, I just don't understand how exactly to receive intents in Android. I want to update a clock app (only when it's in the foreground) every minute. I guess I have to create a class that extends BroadcastReceiver, and implement the method `onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)`, and add an intent filter in my AdroidManifest.xml? How do I add that filter? Is that the only thing that makes the intent received ACTION_TIME_TICK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **Android** SDK reference states, you have to explicitly register for this intent with:

```
Context.registerReceiver().
```